# Is there any way to send commands (like ":screenshot") to the firefox console with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, scripting

I am working on an automation task that opens a webpage, screenshots an element from the page, then closes the page and moves on to the next. I had previously set this up using AutoHotKey and, although it worked technically, I wanted to create a more refined version. Selenium has worked well up to now for automating the navigation of pages, but when I would be ready to take my screenshot, I can't seem to get the console open to issue the command. I tried using the

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'K')
```

command but it seems that firefox doesn't receive the input. I also tried

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'k')
```

which, again, didn't seem to work.

Lastly I tried using

```
browser.execute_script(":screenshot")
```

but I kept getting a JavaScript error which makes sense since the screenshot command isn't js.

If there's anything you can think of that I am overlooking please let me know! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

### **Selenium screenshot**

*Example*

You can take a screenshot of a webpage with the method `get_screenshot_as_file()` with as parameter the filename.
The program below uses firefox to load a webpage and take a screenshot, but any web browser will do.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.python.org')
sleep(1)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

The screenshot image will be stored in the same directory as your Python script. Unless you explicitly define the path where the screenshot has to be stored.

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but because I need to screenshot a specific element, that is larger than the window, the selenium screenshot method won't work. Unless there's some way to specify an element to screenshot with it. Which I don't think there is.

Comment: I’m using it for a variety of websites but the purpose is to capture the content in a screenshot then put all the pages together into a pdf.